# Find $E[Y]$ when $f(x,y) = \frac{x}{3}e^{-xy}$

Tags: distributions, self-study, expected-value, exponential-family, integral

Truth be told, I don't really have an issue with this problem in general, but in it's calculation.  Let me explain.
We need to find $E[Y]$ when $f(x,y) = \frac{x}{3}e^{-xy}$, $1<x<4$ and $y>0$.
So, first I calculated the marginal pdf of $y$ by integrating the joint pdf over the entire domain of $x$, and the calculate $E[Y]$ normally. During the calculation, however, at a point I need to calculate the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-4y}}{y} \ dy$.
I do not know how to solve for this integral. Previously, I have encountered this kind of integral in other problems too, and I don't know how to solve it. The solutions found on the internet are beyond the scope of my syllabus, so I know something that I am doing is wrong and there is a way to avoid this.
So, is there any other approach to solve this sum so that I don't encounter this integral, or even if I do, how do I solve it?

Comment: It looks like you made a mistake.  Either rework your answer or consider an alternative approach, such as computing the marginal of $X$ first or even directly doing the double integral.  Notice that for $x\gt 0,$ $$\int_0^\infty y e^{-xy}\,\mathrm dy = \Gamma(2)\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x}.$$